# make gerrit abort commit push if its message is invalid

Tags: git, githooks, gerrit

I am working with gerrit 2.5.1.

I want to abort commit push from an user if its message does not comply with a format forced by the company.

So, imagine that i want that users only be able to push commits with message formatted like this:

```
[#ISSUENUMBER] Issue Title

Something about the issue

Fix #ISSUENUMBER @5h
```

I already have a script that validates this format, but I have no idea how to add this hook at gerrit and how I get the body message from the commit being pushed. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [ref-update](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-hooks.html#_ref_update) hook or the [commit validator plugins](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/) (which require the soon to be released Gerrit 2.6).